# '98 Passat Locked when FOB batteries changed, how do you unlock it?

Tags: vw, key, passat, fob

My friend owns a '98 VW Passat 2.0 Turbo. He changed the batteries in the key FOB and now the vehicle is locked by the security system. Using the key will not unlock any of the doors or trunk.

What must be done to unlock the vehicle and reset, (if needed), the security system issue?

Comment: Did he try the key?

Comment: @Paulster2 Yes he did, "Using the key will not unlock any of the doors or trunk." For a second I thought I didn't mention it =)

Comment: Although the car has a vacuum actuated lock system that will hold the locks closed, you should be able to use the key to open the drivers door.  There is a micro-switch in the lock mechanism that disengages the vacuum system.  I'm not sure what to do if that doesn't work.

Comment: When he tried the key, how did it fail? Did the key not turn, or did the key turn, but not far enough to open the door? What specifically happened when he tried the key?

Comment: @JonathanMusso - Sorry, I did miss that ... my apologies.

Comment: Is he sure he put the battery in right side up? Is he sure the remote is working at all? Is there a second fob which can be used to open the car?

Comment: @Paulster2 I discovered that he installed the batteries incorrectly. I am waiting to hear back. He was able to get inside the vehicle and start it, but the alarm will not shut off and all 4 windows roll down. Looks like the issue has changed from the original question. Apparently the alarm system may be an issue with the CCM under the driver floor mat, provided he is unable to resolve this by fixing the battery arrangement in the FOB.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Actually no. He ended up breaking his coolant flange and we installed a new one, but there are no more electrical issues that I know of....

Answer (score 1):

Habéis intentado poner las pilas del mando de forma correspondiente  negativo correspondiente con negativo y positivo con positivo?

EDIT: Translate to English through Google Translate and edited for fluency:

Have you confirmed that the batteries are in the remote correctly (negative to negative and positive to positive)?

Comment: This is an English use site. Please post in English if you can. And no, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Upvoted because as far as I can tell, this was the problem. OP to confirm?